# Switching to Inbox while closing

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

Whenever am closing out the iOS SO app, I observed this behavior: though I was in **Questions** list, it switches to **Inbox** - which was previous visited. Always.

1. Visit Inbox
2. Navigate to Questions
3. Double tap the Home button (iPhone 7)
4. Voila it goes to Inbox

[image]

[image]